# Sort by 3 different columns with numbers and text aix

Tags: sort, aix

I am trying to perform a sort by 3 different columns in the correct order on an AIX system.

The below is an extract of a larger file that displays the longest running runtimes between the open brackets e.g. (0 hrs 0 mins 1.030 Secs). Keep in mind that the 1st column will not be in order as the output to the file runs in parallel. So below is the 10 longest running processes out of 2500 lines, which I extracted. Now I would like to sort the top ten longest running process from shortest time to longest time:

```
2023-01-04 12:32:08:       Table seqhi completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iinvd completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table iaudl completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.030 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:11:       Table ccdd_save completed    (1 hrs 0 mins 1.021 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:13:       Table upi_brordrep_tmp_aj completed       (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:07:       Table srdel completed     (0 hrs 2 mins 1.592 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iibt completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table atprdd completed    (0 hrs 0 mins 1.018 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:33:43:       Table atseld completed    (0 hrs 1 mins 33.868 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table abc_irctd completed         (0 hrs 0 mins 1.029 Secs)
```

I want to sort the above by hours minutes and seconds like below:

```
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table atprdd completed    (0 hrs 0 mins 1.018 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:08:       Table seqhi completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iibt completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iinvd completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:13:       Table upi_brordrep_tmp_aj completed       (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table abc_irctd completed         (0 hrs 0 mins 1.029 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table iaudl completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.030 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:33:43:       Table atseld completed    (0 hrs 1 mins 33.868 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:07:       Table srdel completed     (0 hrs 2 mins 1.592 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:11:       Table ccdd_save completed    (1 hrs 0 mins 1.021 Secs)
```

I tried a few sort commands but struggle to get what I would like. How can this be done?

Comment: Why is `12:33:43:` sorted after `12:32:10:`? Also, if you are using AIX pelase mention that in the question instead of using the tag so we can be sure. Finally, did you try `sort`?

Comment: The times on the 1st column is a parallel run to an output file so the 1st column will not be inorder. This is just an extact of many lines simliar to what you see above. I took a subsection of lines out of the file as an example for what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that, specifically tell us what separator your file uses, do you have tabs? Also tell us what OS you are using and if you have tried anything so far. This will require a script to do properly. Do you have `perl` or `python` installed?

Comment: This is an AIX server. Perl is installed. I don't use python on aix

Comment: Are the 3 main columns separated by tab ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the text between  the timestamp and the duration always has 3 blank-separated words like in your sample, you could do:

```
<your-file LC_ALL=C sort -nb -k6.2,6 -k8,8 -k10,10
```

The default separator for `sort` is the transition between a non-blank and a blank, so sort keys without `-b` would include the leading blanks. By using `-b` to strip those, we make sure the first key specified as starting at the second character of the sixth field starts just after the `(`.

All keys are interpreted `n`umerically. With `LC_ALL=C`, we make sure the decimal radix character is expected to be `.` regardless of the locale of the user.

Note that it assumes the seconds and minutes parts don't exceed 60. For instance, it would rank `(0 hrs 1 mins 10.1 Secs)` after `(0 hrs 0 mins 120.592 Secs)` even though the latter is longer.

Pipe to `tail` to get the top-ten.

---

If the sort keys can't be fields or parts of fields with fixed offset, the common approach is to extract the keys using some other tools, copy them at the start of the line, sort and remove them afterwards [in   a *decorate-sort-undecorate* fashion](/search?q=decorate-sort-undecorate):

```
d='\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)'
<your-file sed -n "s/^.*($d hrs $d mins $d\.$d Secs)\$/\1:\2:\3.\4:&/p" |
  LC_ALL=C sort -nt: -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 |
  cut -d: -f4-
```

Or use `perl` which is the best tool for `e`xtraction and `r`eport and has a `sort` operator builtin. [Randal L. Schwartz gave his name to the decorate-sort-undecorate idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) you'd typically use there:

```
<your-file perl -ne '
   push @records, [$_, $3 + 60 * ($2 + 60 * $1)]
     if /\((\d+) hrs (\d+) mins (\d+\.\d+) Secs\)$/;
   END {print $_->[0] for sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @records}'
```

Or use [@terdon's approach](/a/730510) which deduplicates lines with identical duration first, saving some comparisons during sorting but at the expense of manipulating hash tables which might end up being counter productive in terms of efficiency and ends up losing the sorting stability.

Comment: The times will reflect correctly not exceeding 60 for minutes and seconds

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten how did this fail for you? Maybe the `sort` on AIX is missing one of the required options?

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten I'd be surprised if a program that's already apparently parsing the runtime into hours, minutes, and seconds suddenly decides to output values above 59 for the minutes or seconds fields. Or is your comment meant as a general warning?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it is in answer to the warning in Stéphane's answer, see the paragraph starting with "Note that it assumes the seconds and minutes parts don't exceed 60."

Comment: Oh! It's the OP saying "that warning isn't a problem for my situation"; good! It seems to me then, that these comments are all no longer needed?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, terdon's comment was referring to a comment on *his* answer that said my answer didn't work for the OP

Comment: Exactly. This seems like a better approach than mine, so I was hoping the OP would explain how it failed here, where Stéphane would see it and presumably update his answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne '/(\d+)\s*hrs\s*(\d+)\s*mins\s*([0-9.]+)\s*Secs/; 
             push @{$k{($1*60*60)+($2*60)+($3)}},$_; 
             }{ 
             for $t (sort {$a <=> $b} keys(%k)){
                print join "\n",@{$k{$t}}
            }; ' file
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table atprdd completed    (0 hrs 0 mins 1.018 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:08:       Table seqhi completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iibt completed      (0 hrs 0 mins 1.020 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:09:       Table iinvd completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:13:       Table upi_brordrep_tmp_aj completed       (0 hrs 0 mins 1.028 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table abc_irctd completed         (0 hrs 0 mins 1.029 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:10:       Table iaudl completed     (0 hrs 0 mins 1.030 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:33:43:       Table atseld completed    (0 hrs 1 mins 33.868 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:07:       Table srdel completed     (0 hrs 2 mins 1.592 Secs)
2023-01-04 12:32:11:       Table ccdd_save completed    (1 hrs 0 mins 1.021 Secs)
```

This doesn't have the limitation of [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730507/22222), and will correctly sort `(0 hrs 1 mins 10.1 Secs)` before `(0 hrs 0 mins 120.592 Secs)`. On the other hand, that seems like a very unlikely problem and Stéphane's approach is both simpler and faster, so unless you know you have cases with >60 seconds, I would use that one instead.

Comment: Unfortunately Stéphane's approach does not work for me, however your perl solution does work. If there was an easier approach I would use something else...

Answer (score 0):

Warning: the current answer's first line is a (GNU)sort command that wouldn't work on a stock AIX system. (sometimes, gnu-sort is also installed under the name of gsort)

```
sort -k6Vb example
```

Where:

- `-k6` is used do sort from filed 6 up to the end
- `Vb` is version sort (sort that follows human intuition) ignoring leading blanks

(\thanks{Jeff and Stéphane})

Comment: [AIX's sort](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=s-sort-command) doesn't have a `-V` ...

Comment: `-k6,100` is to sort from the start of the 6th field (including the leading blanks) to the end of the 100th. To sort from the 6th to the end, it's just `-k6` (`-bk6` to strip leading blanks from the field)

Comment: @JeffSchaller, thank you: it always difficult to deal with this kind of things. Should I delete My answer?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Thank you

Comment: `-V` is a GNU extension. GNU sort can be installed on AIX. Might be available as `gsort` or as `/opt/gnu/bin/sort`, though likely not out of the box.

Comment: @JJoao I'd keep the answer with enough warning that you're referring to GNU sort; the current Answer's first line is a `sort` command that wouldn't work on a stock AIX system. Not that I'm encouraging copy/paste behavior, but I feel like context is important.

Answer (score 0):

The "sort" command that I am familiar with sorts in alphabetical order rather than numerical order (10,11,12 sorted before 6,7,8) so you may need to add "g" after the -k string (e.g.   "-k8,8g" instead of "-k8,8") to get things to be sorted in numerical order.

Comment: `g` is a GNUism. Here you only need `n` (as a flag to the keys or globally with `-n` as in my answer) though which is standard.